# Libusb issue on Rasperry pi

Tags: c, libusb, magnetic-cards

I am writing an application to communicate with a magnetic band reader through the libusb. in ubuntu 14.04 it works perfectly but in the pi rasperry when I execute the same code it shows me this error:

> libusb: error [reap_for_handle] reap failed error -1 errno=14 libusb:
>   error [handle_events] backend handle_events failed with error -1
>   libusb: error [sync_transfer_wait_for_completion] libusb_handle_events
>   failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_IO, cancelling transfer and retrying,

This happens when he tries to read what comes through the port with the function:

```
u_char * answer ={'\0'};
u_char epAdress;
epAdress=0x81;
r=libusb_bulk_transfer(dev_handle,epAdress,answer,sizeof(answer),&actual, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint `0x81` is an IN endpoint (i.e. device-to-host), since the direction bit (the most significant bit) is 1, which means you are moving data from the device into `answer`.

The problem is that `u_char * answer = {'\0'}` performs scalar initialization, and is equivalent to `uchar * answer = '\0'` and indeed equivalent to `uchar * answer = 0`.

Obviously, writing to memory location `0` will be invalid.  I'm surprised it worked on Ubuntu, maybe the compiler managed to optimize out that write.  What you should write instead is `u_char answer[] = {'\0'}` which will perform array initialization.  Then when you pass `answer` to `libusb_bulk_transfer`, the array type will decay into a pointer type pointing to the start of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved the issue was a bug of the version of libusb that had installed from the default repository .. what I did was download the latest version of it and compile it into the rasperry and that was all worked perfect.

Here's [http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/libusb.html]